# Bitbucket Pipelines section is blank

Tags: git, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I tried with Opera and Chrome, both browsers are constantly updated. I go into the repository,click the "Pipelines" section, but the "content panel" is fully blank.

[image: here what I see]

**Why is that?** and do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I had to switch back and force a few times between the pipeline page and the repo settings page before seeing the normal content for pipelines.
At first, that page was indeed blank.

As seen in "[Get started with Bitbucket Pipelines](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/get-started-with-bitbucket-pipelines-792298921.html)", that content helps you to define and commit a `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` (which holds all the build configurations for your repository) in order for that page to be populated.